# opencv 2.4 SIFT compile error

Tags: opencv, compiler-errors, sift

openCV has changed feature detectors/descriptors (as usually) with new version. I've already found, that I need to add

```
#include "opencv2/nonfree/nonfree.hpp"
#include "opencv2/nonfree/features2d.hpp"
```

however, it still doesn`t work. The error I get is:

```
error: ‘cv::SIFT::DetectorParams’ has not been declare
```

I use standard command for building

```
gcc `pkg-config --cflags --libs opencv` -o descriptorExtractor main.cpp
```

and all the libraries, etc. should be linked correctly

```
pkg-config --cflags --libs opencv

-I/opt/ros/fuerte/include/opencv -I/opt/ros/fuerte/include  -L/opt/ros/fuerte/lib -lopencv_calib3d -lopencv_contrib -lopencv_core -lopencv_features2d -lopencv_flann -lopencv_gpu -lopencv_highgui -lopencv_imgproc -lopencv_legacy -lopencv_ml -lopencv_nonfree -lopencv_objdetect -lopencv_photo -lopencv_stitching -lopencv_ts -lopencv_video -lopencv_videostab
```

What's wrong with openCV again? Please, don't ask me why do I need SIFT from openCV and not from some other software or binary, I just need it...

Comment: If this question is still on, can you give a code sample? If the problem has been resolved, can you post "resolved" as an answer and mark it accepted? Cheers

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I do not remember it well... but I think the issue was that I didn't use

```
cv::initModule_nonfree();
```